# Multimarker tracking using ar_pose

Tags: ar-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm a newcomer to ROS and I'm trying to track an object using ar_pose. I'm able to track several markers at the same time but I don't know how to track an object with several markers like the picture below. [image description http://artoolkit.org/documentation/lib/exe/fetch.php?cache=&media=cube_marker_axes.png](http://artoolkit.org/documentation/lib/exe/fetch.php?cache=&media=cube_marker_axes.png)
I understand the marker.dat file in the data folder but I don't know how to use it  and the demos seems to be broken. Does somebody have a solution ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238368/multimarker-tracking-using-ar_pose/) by [jeanpolochon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27330/jeanpolochon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2016-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend to use [ar_track_alvar](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar) instead. It is able to track marker bundles with `findMarkerBundles` node. A bundle is a set of markers belonging to the same rigid body, like the cube on your photo. The library will always return a pose of the first marker in the bundle, no matter what markers from the bundle are actually visible to the camera.

(Kinetic documentation tab is broken on ROS Wiki, so choose Jade or Indigo tab)

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2016-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1